# Initializing custom UIViewController

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, initialization

I have TabBar based iPhone application, and in app delegate 2 default view controllers are initialized by apple (if you choose tabbar base app when creating application).

```
UIViewController *rootViewController = [[tabBarBetFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabBarBetFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *accountViewController = [[tabBarBetSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabBarBetSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

Why this isn't initialized like this:

```
tabBarBetFirstViewController *rootViewController = [[tabBarBetFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabBarBetFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
tabBarBetSecondViewController *accountViewController = [[tabBarBetSecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"tabBarBetSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
```

???

Is that the same ? Or it's just those default that are added by apple? If i want to add one more tab will I write:

```
UIViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc].....];
```

or

```
ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....];
```

Of course at the end I have:

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rootViewController, accountViewController, third, nil];
```

Comment: just to note, i was using the apple's version, UIViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]...]; and its working... but just want to know whats the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

`ThirdViewController` is a subclass of `UIViewController`, so you can write both. But if you later want to use the variable `third` to invoke methods that are specific to `ThirdViewController`, then you should use

```
ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....];
```

Summing it up: In this simple scenario there is no single right way of "doing it". The important lesson to take from this question (if it wasn't clear already) is to understand *why* you can assign a `ThirdViewController` instance to a `UIViewController` variable (because of the subclassing relationship).

Comment: ohh, that makes sense :D . well, i use it just in app delegate (like i wrote) so in that case dont invoke any methods on that, just add them to tabbarcontroller... thx

Answer (score 0):

You use the

```
ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....];
```

approach. Don't know why Apple uses the other approach. I this easy example it doesn't make any difference. But when you have properties you want to set it's better to use the class name.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, if you have a view controller that you want to have a custom interface, you will want it to be a subclass of UIViewController. If ThirdViewController is a subclass of UIViewController then that code that you stated here:

```
ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....];
```

Would produce the desired result. Apple's approach is just for a generic View Controller without any properties, so ideally you would want all of your tabs to be UIViewController subclasses.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you want to make use of any instance methods or properties in your ThirdViewController, then you must use

```
ThirdViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....];
```

2) If you dont have a need to do so, you can use

```
UIViewController *third = [ThirdViewController alloc]....]; // it'd make no difference
```

To be on a safer side, imo, first case is a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In this case I do not see any difference, I would prefer doing it your way. But in a situation similar to the one below, Apple's way seems better:

```
UIViewController *vc;

if ( some_case ){

    vc = [YourViewController1 alloc]// ...;
    [ (YourViewController1 *) vc doSomeThing]; // You might need to use casting for instance messages
    //...
}

else {

    vc = [YourViewController2 alloc]//...;
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
[vc release];
```